# How does one use Fermi's Golden Rule to calculate two-body rate of collision for a 1-D Fermi gas?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, collision, scattering, fermions, fermis-golden-rule

I am trying to verify a simulation I made of a bunch of non-interacting fermions (except elastic collisions) in a harmonic potential by comparing the rate of collisions from my simulation by using a counter to calculate the numerator in the formula:
$$rate=\frac{ No\ \  of\  \  rebounds}{No.\ \  of\ \ particles\ \ \times\ Time} $$

where the number of rebounds is the nimber of rebounds from oppistely spin particle collisions only.

My simulation yields answers of order $10^{-2}$ for a particular value of a parameter $\alpha$  $(=\sqrt n)$ which is related to the 1D scattering length (this relation is not important here). The reflection coefficient depends on this parameter as follows:
$$r=\frac{1}{1+\alpha^2}$$
And it is important to note that by collision I mean a rebound collision. They could collide and transmit through each other but I only count those for which they rebound.

The position and momenta of the particles are sampled from a gaussian.

An estimate calculation for the order can be done as follows:

If there are $N$ particles on a unit line then the distance between them is $1/N$ and since relative velocity is $\sim 1$  the time of a single collision is also $\sim 1/N$ therefore the rate of collision becomes $\sim $ N such that only for rebounds it is $\sim \ Nr$ which for $\alpha=\sqrt N$ gives the rate of rebound $\sim \frac{N}{1+\alpha^2}\sim N/N\sim 1 $

This is a hundred factors off my simulation and the reason I am guessing is that I have done the estimate poorly since the particles are not at equal distances from each other even initially since their position and momenta are sampled from a gaussian.

So, I am trying to calculate the exact rate of rebound but the calculation seems difficult to me. I have done it so far as follows:
If $\gamma$ be the rate of collision we know it should depend on the number density so that:
$$dColl=\gamma(n)dNdt$$ where $n=n(z)$ and $dN=n(z)dz$ such that:
$$\Gamma=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \gamma(n) n(z)dz \int dt}{N \int dt }=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \gamma(n) n(z)dz}{N}$$

I am trying to find $\gamma(z)$ using Fermi's golden rule:
The two -particle collision has the delta potential scattering in the COM frame with potential given as:

$$V=\frac{Q}{L}\sum_{k1+k2=k1'+k2'}a^{\dagger}_{k1}b^{\dagger}_{k2}b^{\dagger}_{k3}a^{\dagger}_{k4}$$
Then $$\Gamma(k_o)=\frac{2pi}{\hbar}\sum_f\delta(E_f-E_i)|\langle f|V|i \rangle|^2$$such that
$$\Gamma=\int\Gamma(k_0)e^{-\frac{k_o^2}{2}}dk_0$$

I don't know how to proceed from here.

The initial state I think (I am really unsure about this because I think the state of a fermion cannot be simply be described with a momentum state and spin since it's in a harmonic potential) can be written as (in momentum state $k_o$ with spin down:
$$|i \rangle=|k_o, {\downarrow} \rangle$$

while the final state can be all possible permutations of spin-ups about this spin down in 1D. (Note how I am ignoring collision with spin-down particles):

$$|f \rangle=| k_1, \{N_{\uparrow}\} \rangle$$

Also, I tried to piece the above calculations from different sources and have not studied this problem in any book yet. I am not sure therefore if the logic is correct. It would be helpful if I could get directions to a reference for this topic too besides the help for the main problem so that I can do this with full understanding again rigorously.